# C# word array help in Winforms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

So in my class we are doing a pig latin translator using Winforms.  If I copy the formula from my Convert function to the click event it works perfectly fine for 1 word.  However I can not get this to function correctly otherwise.

This is the code I currently have, the problem it is giving me is that the output label is not giving me the converted word.  Instead it is giving me this message:

For example say I input 'Bob'
I get this as my output:
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]Bob"

```
    private void btn_Translate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userInput = box_Input.Text;
        if (userInput.Contains(" "))
        {
            string[] words = userInput.Split(' ');
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                Validator(word);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Validator(userInput);
        }

    }
    public void Validator(string s)
    {
        string chkInput = s;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chkInput))
        {
            Error(1);
            Error(0);
        }
        else
        {
            if (chkInput.Length < 2)
            {
                Error(1);
                Error(0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!chkInput.Any(x => char.IsLetter(x)))
                {
                    Convert(chkInput);
                }
                else
                {
                    Error(3);
                    Error(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Convert(string convInput)
    {
        string word = convInput;
        string charStrNew;
        string firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
        string theRest = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
        string suffix = "ay";
        charStrNew = $"{theRest}{firstLetter}{suffix}";
        string listStrOutput = String.Join(" ", charStrNew);

        lbl_Output.Text = listStrOutput;
    }
```

Comment: code seems to be fine. Where do you get the exception? in which line? https://dotnetfiddle.net/i3foSQ

Comment: It would never throw an error.  It was able to process the data, it was just processing it the wrong way.  @aloisdg found it for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your `Validator`. Replace the `!chkInput.Any(x => char.IsLetter(x))` with `!chkInput.Any(x => !char.IsLetter(x))` or even better, use [`Enumerable.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0): `chkInput.All(char.IsLetter)`

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

[msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0)

```
public static void Main()
{
    btn_Translate_Click("bob");
}

public static void btn_Translate_Click(string userInput)
{
    if (userInput.Contains(" "))
    {
        string[] words = userInput.Split(' ');
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            Validator(word);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Validator(userInput);
    }

}

public static void Error(int output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

public static void Validator(string s)
{
    string chkInput = s;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chkInput))
    {
        Error(1);
        Error(0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (chkInput.Length < 2)
        {
            Error(1);
            Error(0);
        }
        else
        {
            if (chkInput.All(char.IsLetter))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert(chkInput));
            }
            else
            {
                Error(3);
                Error(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static string Convert(string convInput)
{
    string word = convInput;
    string charStrNew;
    string firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
    string theRest = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
    string suffix = "ay";
    charStrNew = $"{theRest}{firstLetter}{suffix}";
    string listStrOutput = String.Join(" ", charStrNew);

    return listStrOutput;
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d3HGtU)

Comment: Good god thank you.  Man I've been starting at this for hours and finding nothing wrong.  Apparently I just needed some fresh eyes.